# Default construct an optional function parameter

Tags: c++, optional-parameters, c++03, default-constructor

I want to design a function so that the parameter is optional and default constructed if left out. The parameter is a struct that I've defined in the same header file. The tried to use the following function declaration:

```
void publish(MarkerStyle style=MarkerStyle());
```

When I try to compile I get the following error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘bob::MarkerStyle::MarkerStyle(bob::MarkerStyle)’
  void publish(MarkerStyle style=MarkerStyle());
```

Is there some way to invoke the default constructor of MarkerStyle as an optional parameter?

EDIT:

Here is my header file.

```
struct MarkerStyle()
{
    double alpha;
    std::auto_ptr<Color> color;

    MarkerStyle() :
    alpha(100) 
    {}
};

class Publisher
{
   void publish(MakerStyle style=MarkerStyle());
};
```

I understand Bo Perreson's answer. Now my question is why doesn't my code generate a copy constructor for MarkerStyle?

EDIT:

I figured out the problem. auto_ptr prevented copy constructor generation.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: That "definition" looks like a *declaration*.

Comment: Does your class have a well-formed, non-explicit copy-constructor?

Comment: No, there is no copy constructor. I have defined a constructor, though. Does that prevent the automatic copy constructor generation?

Comment: it looks like you just didnt declare the definition properly...

Comment: @user2445507 you need to provide a declaration of class `MarkerStyle`

Comment: You have typos and invalid syntax. Are you posting real code?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `MarkerStyle` by value, it will get copied and you need a copy constructor.

If you don't want or need a copy, pass it by const reference, like

```
void publish(MarkerStyle const& style=MarkerStyle());
```

Comment: Although there isn't anything to suggest the class is not copy-constructable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the copy constructor would be invoked. I made an edit. If you look at my header, can you see why there would not be an auto-generated copy-constructor?  I may go with const reference anyways.

Comment: I realize now that auto_ptr prevented copy constructor generation. Or at least I think that's it. Thanks